# How to read files from USB mass storage in Jenkinsfile in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I have Jenkins job in which I want to read files from USB mass storage connected to a Linux machine where Jenkins is also running.
I have permission issues to open or copy files. USB device is mounted for another user than jenkins.
Any suggestion how to fix this issue?